# Resolution of monitor is not supported by motherboard

Tags: display, upgrade, motherboard

I have Desktop with configuration
Pentium 4,945 intel chipset board,dual booting with win 7 and ubuntu 10.10 (no graphics card)
Recently i purchased Dell IN2020M 20" with native resolution of 1600x900
but my display allow maximum of 1024x768 because of this when i play any video in full screen mode it doesn't play smoothly or frames are refreshed jerkily

I have tried updating my VGA driver but its doesn't helping me much.
Is there any way to solve this problem ?

1>if i want to replace monitor what maximum resolution should i buy ? 
2>if i want to upgrade(graphics card/motherboard) my desktop what is the minimum configuration to  support the current system.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try if anything changes when you install the dirver for the monitor (yeah there actually is such thing). It should be shipped on a CD with the monitor or you can download it on the dell website (http://support.us.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R269753&formatcnt=0&libid=0&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=398084 ??)